# Needs information regarding type casting in Instanceof Operator

Tags: java, instanceof

Following `instanceof` operator is working fine, when I type cast string to Object.

However, Without typecasting it is failing to compile.

```
public class Test {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            boolean b1 = "abc" instanceof Integer; // Compilation fails
            boolean b2 = ((Object) "abc") instanceof Integer; // Works fine
        }
    }
```

My question is why compiler is rejecting the first one `b1` but allowing the second one `b2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[JLS 15.20 and 15.20.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.20.2) state this:

> ```
> RelationalExpression:
>   ...
>   RelationalExpression instanceof ReferenceType
> ```
>
> If a cast of the `RelationalExpression` to the `ReferenceType` would be rejected as a compile-time error ([§15.16](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.16)), then the `instanceof` relational expression likewise produces a compile-time error. *In such a situation, the result of the instanceof expression could never be true.*

In your first example expression (`"abc" instanceof Integer`) `"abc"` (a `String`) cannot be cast to `Integer`.  Therefore the `instanceof` expression is a compilation error.

In your second example expression (`((Object) "abc") instanceof Integer`), the left operand has type `Object`.  In some cases, an `Object` may be an `Integer`.  Therefore the left-hand operand *can* be cast to the right-hand type.  Therefore the `instanceof` is allowed.

It is worth noting that the JLS is only concerning itself with the compile-time types of the expressions.  In the second example, we can easily deduce that the run-time type of the left hand operand is always `String` and the expression will always evaluate to `false`.  But the JLS rules don't classify this "mistake" as a compilation error.

Comment: Excellent finding. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Because you've casted `"abc"` to `Object`, the compiler treats `((Object) "abc")` the same as any other expression of `Object` type.

As such, it thinks that it could contain any `Object` (or null). The compiler doesn't deeply inspect the expression to determine a more specific type.

You can also write:

```
Object obj = "abc";
boolean b2 = obj instanceof Integer;
```

It's basically the same.

It stops you writing `"abc" instanceof Integer` because both `String` and `Integer` are classes, and they are unrelated, so a `String` can never be an instance of an `Integer`. (It would allow `"abc" instanceof List`, because `List` is an interface, and it doesn't consider the final-ness of a class, and assumes there might be a subclass of `String` that could implement `List`).

In a sense, casting is you telling the compiler that you know more than it does. Although the compiler is able to push back in very basic cases where it can determine that you are doing something nonsensical, it largely gets out of the way and trusts you (in a "on your head be it" kind of way).

Answer (score 0):

Instanceof can only be used between parent and child classes

the first one "abc" is String type not Integer.
but the second one ((Object) "abc") is Object type,  Integer is a child of Object